# Mysql: I am getting this error: Duplicate entry ' 'index_name'.

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql: I am getting this error: Duplicate entry ' 'index_name'.

The URI in the 'url' columns contain a query parameter '?'. I would like to remove everything right of '?' and update the column with everything left of '?'. The URIs look like the following:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/browse/team-sports/football/4125_4161_434036?povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L277
http://www.mydomain.com/browse/sports-outdoors/golf/4125_4152?povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L278
http://www.mydomain.com/browse/team-sports/volleyball/4125_4161_1041862/?povid=P1171-C1110.2784+1455.2776+1115.2956-L282
http://www.mydomain.com/browse/christmas-decor/holiday-lighting/2637_633379_1025279
http://www.mydomain.com/browse/christmas-decor/holiday-lighting/2637_633379_1025279/?povid=P1171-C1093.2766-L109
```

The query I am trying to run is:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET url = SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '?', 1)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Duplicate entry 'http://www.mydomain.com/browse/biography-memoirs/multi-cultural/3' for key 'index_name'
```

I've tried deleting all duplicates and dropping the unique index to no avail.

Your time and advice would be much appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Is the url column declard as a unique. Seems you add an identitical entry into a unique defined column.

Comment: provide your complete update query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INSERT INORE INTO syntax when updating on unique columns.

`INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable (Url) Values(yourvalue) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Url=yourvalue;'`

This will insert the value if it doesnt exist and update it if does exists.

Otherwise create a identical new table and insert from this table

`INSERT INTO newtable SELECT SUBSTRING(Url,'?',1) FROM mytable group by substring(Url,'?',1)`

This should take care that no duplicates are inserted.

Answer (score 3):

you have a unique key constraint called `index_name` in the col `url`.
this is why this error occures.

to solve it: either remove the key or fix your update.